# misunderstanding ember changes in "Ember Data : 1.13.12 "

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I updated Ember Data to version 1.13.12  and got some problems with my old sources.

Example:

I have code

```
   this.store.find('user', params).then(function(results) {
     self.get('experts').addObjects(results); // add users to 'experts' filed in controller
  });
```

In "Ember Data : 1.13.12" code below does not works, fall with error:

```
  "TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getRecord'"
```

Solution which I found

```
   self.get('experts.content').addObjects(results.get('content'));
```

The next problem:

```
  return this.store.query('review', {'expert_id': expertId}).then(function(data){
        data.get('content').forEach(function(item) {
            item.set('currentUser', self.modelFor('e'));
        });
        return data;
    });
```

`item` was a object of `Class` and now it's a object of `DS.INTERNALMODEL` which not contain `set` method

From the debugger I found solution:

```
  item.record.set('currentUser', self.modelFor('e'));
```

QUESTION:
All my solution looks like not good, what changed in new ember data? 
What is the best practice to solve this problems?

I read change log and didn't find any information which refer to my problems

Comment: Some info can be found in ember blog: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html#toc_simplified-find-methods

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `forEach` on `data` instead of `data.content` since `store.query` resolves with `RecordArray` which extends `ArrayProxy`:

```
return this.store.query('review', { expert_id: expertId}).then((data) => {
    let model = self.modelFor('e');
    data.forEach((item) => {
        item.set('currentUser', model);
    });
    return data;
});
```